# CFS sysctl_sched_latency kernel parameter

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

We have following kernel parameters:

```
sysctl_sched_min_granularity = 0.75
sysctl_sched_latency = 6 ms
sched_nr_latency = 8
```

What I understand (I don't know if correctly), parameter `sysctl_sched_latency` says, that all tasks in runqueue should be executed in time `6ms`.

So if the task arrives in `time X` the task should be executed not later than `X + 6 ms` at least once.

The function `check_preempt_tick` is executed periodically by `task_tick_fair`.

At the beginning of this function we checks whether `delta_exec` is `not greater` then `ideal_runtime`:

```
ideal_runtime = sched_slice(cfs_rq, curr);
delta_exec = curr->sum_exec_runtime - curr->prev_sum_exec_runtime;

if (delta_exec > ideal_runtime)
```

For instance:

- if we have `4 tasks` (the same priority) `ideal_runtime` should returns `1.5 ms` for the first task.

Let assume that this task has executed for `1.5 ms` and `exit`.

- So we have `3 tasks` in the `queue` right now.

The second calculation for `task2` is like that:

- we have `3 tasks` in a queue so time of `ideal_runtime` should be `2 ms`.
- `Task2` has run for `2 ms` and `exit`.

Again

- `task3` calculates time and we have
- `2 tasks` in the `queue`
- so it should run for `3ms`.

So in summary

- `task4` will be executed after `1.5 ms (task1) + 2ms (task2) + 3ms (task3)`
- so `sysctl_sched_latency` is exceeded (which is 6 ms).

How `CFS` does ensure that all task in queue are executed in `sysctl_sched_latency` time, when queue can change dynamically all time?

Thanks,